# Scanner doesn't read user input after exception

Tags: java

Why doesn't Scanner read the value after an exception occurs? Here is the code. When an exception is thrown, on the next iteration it doesn't allow the user to input data, it always goes to the catch block and prints text.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean correctInput = false;
        do {
            try {
                int readInt = inputScanner.nextInt();
                correctInput = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                correctInput = false;
                System.out.println("Please enter int value");
            }
        } while (!correctInput);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use exceptions for controlling the flow of your code. Use ``while(!scanner.hasNextInt())`` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`nextInt` doesnt consume non-integer values so any such input will be passed *ad infinitum* to the exception block once the exception occurs. Therefore you need to consume this value

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.err.println("Invalid integer: " + inputScanner.nextLine());
      ...
}
```

or better simply use `hasNextInt`

```
while (inputScanner.hasNextInt()) {
  ... // no boolean flag needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            correctInput = false;
            System.out.println("Please enter int value");
            inputScanner.next();
   }
```

consume one token and continue

Answer (score -1):

I actually just solved this exact problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = 0;
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        // running `hasNextInt` the first time causes the program to stop and wait for user input
        // then it checks it the user input is a valid int, and writes whether it is to `valid`
        boolean valid = sc.hasNextInt();
        // running `hasNextInt` again will always give the same return value, because it will reuse the input value that the scanner was already given
        // i.e. `hasNextInt` actually behaves differently, and only after the first call
        if(valid){
            // this uses the string of text that `hasNextInt` scanned, instead of scanning new text
            // therefore, this won't wait for the user and this just runs
            result = sc.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        // implied else
        // once again, this code just runs, and in this case, it removes the text that `hasNextInt` scanned earlier
        sc.next(); // therefore, we void the current input because it is invalid
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
    // use results
    System.out.println("Did you know that " + result + " is " + (
        // here is your daily dose of bad code
        (new String[]{"even", "odd"})[result % 2]
    ) + "?");
    sc.close();
}
```

I hope the comments are explanatory.